# setting up OpenCL with DirectX 9

Tags: directx, opencl

I'm completely new to OpenCL and GPU programming in general. Right now I am working on a project where I'm trying to see the performance saves that making use of the GPU in a game has. With this, however, I have ran into a snag; how do I set up my Directx project to speak to the OpenCL code base?

I've been googling this for about a week and haven't been able to find anything. If someone could point me in the right direction, I would be greatful.

Comment: You probably haven't found an answer, since 'how do I set up my Directx project to speak to the OpenCL code base?' doesn't really make much sense. DirectX and OpenCL are both distinct APIs. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm trying to make my project make use of GPUs to speed up performance. To access the GPUs I am going to be using OpenCL as the language. My problem is; how do I get my C++ / DirectX code to accept the new OpenCL API code? I can't find anything to set up the project like you can with DirectX programs. Like what do i need to link? etc

Comment: FYI, DirectX leverages the GPU as well (via Direct3D at a minimum), so adding in OpenCL won't really benefit the graphics any (and if the game is graphically intense, putting *more* work on the GPU's shoulders probably isn't the best idea!).

Comment: DirectCompute (I assume your talking about?) is DirectX 10 and above IIRC. It's not putting more work on it, it's making it work smarter to do the same task, hopefully speeding up performance. Thank you for the helpful response with the rest of your comment as well.

Comment: @N0Xus I don't think you understand what OpenCL or DirectX is. Both are APIs that allow direct access to the GPU. DirectX is specific for graphics and other multimedia operations, so it will actually be faster than OpenCL for most graphic related operations. OpenCL just lets access to the GPU for more general purpose programming. So taking that into account, your question of 'how do I get my C++ / DirectX code to accept the new OpenCL API code?' doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @onit - I know what both are. I am trying to use OpenCL to compute more of the graphics/data computation on the GPU to free up the CPU. That way i can do things like this: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfrM973spw0 I want to know how I would go about setting up the project so that it can talk to both API's in a single project.

Comment: @N0Xus If you need to use OPenCL, link OpenCL. If you need to use DirectX, link DirectX. If you need both, link both.

Answer (score 1):

OpenCL does not have anything to do with DirectX, it's simply another library.

For OpenCL you'll need an implementation ('SDK'), as Khronos don't provide those (they only provide the specifications).
Intel, AMD and Nvidia all provide one, but they have different requirements and limitations. [See here for some of the existing implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenCL#OpenCL_conformant_products)

After installing one of these, you'll have the necessary headers and libraries to code against the OpenCL API and link with OpenCL.dll

There are lots of sample sources in the SDKs or online, you have to write the kernel, the rest is mostly boilerplate code for initialization and kernel compilation.

Answer (score 1):

The specific OpenCL extension that allows sharing of OpenCL buffers as textures and vice versa is cl_khr_d3d10_sharing.txt. http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_d3d10_sharing.txt

Answer (score 0):

OpenCL has extensions for sharing memory between DirectX and OpenCL (and also between OpenGL and OpenCL.) This allows you to read or write DirectX buffers, including textures from within OpenCL. Ani's answer mentioned the extension for DirectX 10, but since the question is about DirectX 9, the extension you'll actually be using is [cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing.html).

This extension has just 4 functions:

#### [clGetDeviceIDsFromDX9MediaAdapterKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clGetDeviceIDsFromDX9MediaAdapterKHR.html)

This function allows you to get the OpenCL device IDs of the OpenCL device(s) that can share memory with a given Direct3D 9 device.

#### [clCreateFromDX9MediaSurfaceKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateFromDX9MediaSurfaceKHR.html)

This function gets an OpenCL `cl_mem` memory object for a given Direct3D 9 memory object.

#### [clEnqueueAcquireDX9MediaSurfacesKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueAcquireDX9MediaSurfacesKHR.html)

This function locks the specified shared memory object so that you can read and/or write to it from OpenCL.

#### [clEnqueueReleaseDX9MediaSurfacesKHR](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.0/docs/man/xhtml/clEnqueueReleaseDX9MediaSurfacesKHR.html)

This function unlocks the specified memory object from OpenCL, so that Direct3D can read/write it again.

---

Once you've used the above functions to share and synchronize access to the memory buffers, everything else on both the Direct3D 9 side and the OpenCL side works as it would otherwise with those particular APIs.

Note that your GPU will need to support the cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing extension in order for this to work. You can check the extensions property of the OpenCL platform and device in order to confirm that this extension is supported.

Some NVidia GPUs support a different extension instead, called [cl_nv_d3d9_sharing](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/extensions/nv/cl_nv_d3d9_sharing.txt). The basic idea of how it works is the same as with the cl_khr_dx9_media_sharing extension, but the exact details are a bit different. The biggest difference is just that it has different functions for getting `cl_mem` objects for different types of Direct3D 9 buffers, rather than just one function to cover all of them.